# Computed column '...' in table '...' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following function.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Valid](@c char(9))
RETURNs bit
as
begin
    DECLARE @sum int = 0;
    return 0 
end
```

And the following SQL

```
create table test(A char(10))
alter table test add C as dbo.Valid(A) persisted;
```

has the error of

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
>
> Computed column 'C' in table 'test' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions must be decorated with the [`WITH SCHEMABINDING`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140382/140226) hint, otherwise SQL Server skips the validation of determinism (a performance optimization), and treats that default result as not being deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

As Elaskanator stated, you should add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` at the definition of your function like below:

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[Valid](@c char(9))
RETURNS BIT WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
begin
    DECLARE @sum int = 0;
    return 0 
END

create table test(A char(10))
alter table test add C AS dbo.Valid(A) persisted;
```

More info: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3338/change-all-computed-columns-to-persisted-in-sql-server/